# How to extract 3D matrix from N-D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on 5D matrix configured as follow :

```
[nf,nx,ny,np,nz]=size(D);
```

such

```
nf=301; 
nx=12; 
ny=12; 
np=12; 
nz=12;
```

I need to extract two matrices from this 5D matrix D :

- The first `A`, such  `[nf,nx,ny]=size(A);`
- The second `B`, such `[nf,np,nz]=size(B);`

Is there any MATLAB codes to extract these two matrices from `D` ?

Comment: There are 144 possibilities for A and 144 possibilities for B that can be obtained through simple indexing. Which are you looking for?

Comment: Dear Mad Physicist, I need a code that would allow me to extract B and A whatever the possibility but without changing the nature of the data. Thanks

Comment: If you want to extract a square on a chessboard you have to select a square, for example C5. Your code cannot guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to choose specific subscripted index values for two dimensions, extract the data from your [multidimensional array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), then collapse the resulting dimensions of length 1 using the [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function as needed. Here's how it would work for `A` and `B`:

```
pIndex = 2;  % Second index of dimension 4
zIndex = 3;  % Third index of dimension 5
A = D(:, :, :, pIndex, zIndex);  % Don't need squeeze because they
                                 %   are the trailing dimensions

xIndex = 1;   % First index of dimension 2
yIndex = 12;  % Last index of dimension 3
B = squeeze(D(:, xIndex, yIndex, :, :));
```

Note that using a [colon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) as an index will include all subscripts from that dimension.

Comment: Thanks Dear for answer. It works very well as I expected. thank !

Comment: @YAPO: Happy to help. Don't forget that you can mark an answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) when it solves your problem.